# How to programmatically check if all images from a compose file are running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I want to programmatically `up` a `docker-compose.yml` file in `--detach` mode then wait and block the application until all images of the compose file get up as `Containers` so that I can run my integration tests.

Notice that `docker-compose images`, and `docker-compose inspect` are useless since they are unable to detect anything until the containers run.

**More details:**
I want to implement it as an abstract library which works with any docker-compose.yml file, and I want the library to be used by F# on dotnet core. There are some solutions around that need to be used on linux, but I don't want to limit the developers to use a special OS or tool other than the F#, dotnet core, docker, and docker-compose CLI

Comment: Why the `F#` tag?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the docker-compose file you are using? Knowing more about your services will help to provide a better answer.

Comment: @Eugene Fotin: As I told I want to do it programmatically. The F# flag is because I want to implement it by F#

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu I want it to work with every docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

From this [docker-compose PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5643) (version >= 1.20.0) (which is have been already merged) `docker-compose ps` shows whether each service is healthy or not. So, defining a **healthcheck** on each [service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) or [image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) and executing `docker-compose ps` will tell if your services are available.

The column State of `docker-compose ps` is:

- For starting: **Up (health: starting)**
- For no health check: **Up**
- For healthy: **Up (healthy)**
- For unhealthy: **Up (unhealthy)**

For instance for an `postresql` service, a healtcheck might be:

```
...
  postgres:                                                                                                                                   
    image: postgres:9.6
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "lsof", "-i:5432"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
 ...
```

You will need `lsof` available on your image. You can also use `nc`, `telnet`, `netstat` or a more specific tool for the service, like `pgsql`.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. Does it check the health before the containers start? The main problem is to check whether the container is started or not. If it does, could you please add some implementation detail please?

Comment: Healtcheck check from the moment the containers starts. I added an generic example, since I do not have any knowledge about your services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/README.md) to wait until some port is listen to execute a command.

For instance:

```
wait-for-it.sh <IP>:<port> -- <execute-tests-command>
```